# How to solve this equation by integration

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

If x is a function of y: x(y)

Can this equation be solved ?

$$
\frac{x’’}{x}-\frac{x’}{x^2} -  \frac{x’^2}{x^2} =0,
$$

My trial I have multiplied by $\frac{x}{x’}$:

$$
\frac{x’’}{x’}-  \frac{x’}{x} -\frac{1}{x}  =0.
$$

Since $\frac{d}{dy} log ~f(y)= \frac{f’}{f}$
This will be

$$
log~ x’ - log~ x = \int \frac{1}{x} dy + C, ~~~~ \star
$$

( is this step right? ). I think from here an integral of $x’$ should be done. Anyways any idea how to find x(y), to be something similar to:

$$
x(y) = ( Q_y + 1)^{\frac{1}{4C-B+1}},
$$

where $Q_y$ is a function of y, and C and B are constants.

Comment: "trail" ≠ "trial".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{x’’}{x}-\frac{x’}{x^2} -  \frac{x’^2}{x^2} =0,$$
$$\frac{xx’'-x'^2}{x^2}=\frac{x’}{x^2} $$
$$\left(\frac{x'}{x}\right)'=-\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)' $$
Reduce the order of the DE by integration.

---

Edit
$$\left(\frac{x'}{x}\right)'=-\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)' $$
$$\frac{x'}{x}=-\frac{1}{x} +C $$
$$x'=Cx-1 $$
This DE is separable.
$$\frac{dx}{Cx-1}=dy$$

Comment: Hi @user577215664, I think this’s similar to my solution trail, equ. $\star$. My question is how to integrate $(ln~x)’’$ or $x^{-1}$ with respect to y.

Comment: I added some lines hope it's clear The DE is separable at the end....@Dr.phy

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome @Dr.phy

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to solve this equation : switch variables and write it as
$$-\frac 1x \frac{ y''}{[y']^3}-\frac 1{x^2}\frac 1{ y'}-\frac 1{x^2}\frac 1{ [y']^2}=0$$ that is to say
$$x y''+y'+[y']^2=0$$ and the reduction of order becomes obvious. With $p=y'$
$$x p'+p+p ^2=0$$
$$p=\frac 1 q \implies x q'=1+q\implies q=c_1x-1\implies p=\frac 1{c_1 x-1}$$ Just finish and inverse.

Comment: Hi @ClaudeLeibovici. I don’t get the first step where you switched the variables, how did you substitute by $x’’= -\frac{y’’}{y’^3}, x’=y’^{-1}$ and $x’^2=y’^{-2}$. And also the last line, I don't get why after setting $p=y’$, you called $p=\frac{1}{q}$. Then how $p=\frac{1}{c_1 x-1} $ is reached. And if we returned and substituted by $p=y’$ ( is that what you mean by finish and inverse? ) , how will we make this integral then? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$x'=0$ gives constant functions as solutions.

On segments where $x'\ne 0$ one can parametrize $x'=u(x)$ to get
$$
xu'(x)=1+u(x)\implies 1+u(x)=Cx\implies x'=Cx-1.
$$
This is again elementary to solve,
$$
Cx(t)-1=De^{Ct}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

To solve a differential equation in $x$, you cannot express the solution in terms of an antiderivative of $x.$ The entire point of the theory is that we would like to avoid doing this, and instead, we want to express $x$ entirely in terms of other functions that have nothing to do with $x,$ functions that are known in the stipulation of the problem.

Here is the approach I suggest: rewrite $$\frac{x''}{x'}-\frac{x'}{x^2}-\frac{x'^2}{x^2}=0$$ as $$\frac{xx''-x'^2}{x^2}=\frac{x'}{x^2},$$ which is equivalent to $$\left(\frac{x'}{x}\right)'=\left(-\frac1{x}\right)',$$ which can be rewritten as $$\left(\frac{x'+1}{x}\right)'=0.$$ This implies $$\frac{x'+1}{x}=C_-$$ for $x\lt0$ and $$\frac{x'+1}{x}=C_+$$ for $x\gt0.$ These are equivalent to $x'+1=C_-x$ and $x'+1=C_+x,$ or $x'=C_-\left(x-\frac1{C_-}\right)$ and $x'=C_+\left(x-\frac1{C_+}\right)$ if $C_-,C_+\neq0.$ Otherwise, we simply have $x'=-1,$ which is simply solved by $x(t)=C-t.$ The two former equations are separable, with $$\frac{x'}{x-\frac1{C_-}}=C_-,\,\frac{x'}{x-\frac1{C_+}}=C_+.$$ So we have that $$\ln\left[-\left(x-\frac1{C_-}\right)\right]=C_-t-A_-$$ for $x\lt{\frac1{C_-}},x\lt0,$ $$\ln\left(x-\frac1{C_-}\right)=C_-t-A_+$$ for $x\gt{\frac1{C_-}},x\lt0,$ $$\ln\left[-\left(x-\frac1{C_+}\right)\right]=C_+t-A_-$$ for $x\lt{\frac1{C_+}},x\gt0,$ $$\ln\left(x-\frac1{C_+}\right)=C_+t-A_+$$ for $x\gt{\frac1{C_+}},x\gt0.$ Respectively, this implies $$x-\frac1{C_-}=-\exp(A_-)\exp(C_-t),$$ $$x-\frac1{C_-}=\exp(A_+)\exp(C_-t),$$ $$x-\frac1{C_+}=-\exp(A_-)\exp(C_+t),$$ $$x-\frac1{C_+}=\exp(A_+)\exp(C_+t).$$